# copy data from one excel workbook to master workbook by pushing button

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Is it possible to save into another workbook instead of same workbook. we are making a master workbook. daily we are updating data, once updated by pushing button need to copy in to master workbook with sheet name as current date.

below code working for copying into same work book into sheet2

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

On Error GoTo Err_Execute

Sheet1.Range("A1:J75").Copy 
Sheet2.Range("A1").Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown

Err_Execute:

If Err.Number = 0 Then

MsgBox "All have been copied!"

ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 Then

MsgBox Err.Description

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: of course you can. just add the reference to the desired workbook via `Workbooks` collection (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224504(v=office.11).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You just have to set the Workbooks properly to be able to refer to them:

```
Dim masterWB As Workbook
Dim dailyWB As Workbook

'Set Current Workbook as Master
Set masterWB = Application.ThisWorkbook
'Set some Workbook as the one you are copying from
Set dailyWB = Workbooks.Open("PATH TO WORKBOOK HERE")

'Copy the Range from the Workbook and Paste it into the MasterWB
dailyWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1:J75").Copy masterWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Rows("1:1")

Close the Workbook without saving
dailyWB.Close False
'Clear the Variables
Set dailyWB = Nothing
Set masterWB = Nothing
```

Just modify the Sheets to match your needs and it should work

If you want to create a Worksheet on your Master Workbook and Rename it use this:

```
Dim tempWS as Worksheet
Set tempWS = masterWB.Sheets.Add

tempWS.Name = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy")
```

Depending on the Format you want to use for the name, modify the "mm-dd-yyyy" to your needs. e. g. "yyyy.mm.dd"